# Frame rate (FPS) multiplied by duration (sec) isn't equal to total frames

Tags: video, youtube, frame-rate, codec

On a YouTube video stats, apparently, the frame rate is 30 fps:

[image: Stats]

Total video length is `1:32` i.e. `92` sec.

[image: duration]

Total frames `=` frame rate `x` time

Total frames `= 30 x 92 = 2760`

So why are frames reported as `8704`? Or maybe I'm wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That stat is there to know if your browser has problems playing the video. It doesn't show the frames downloaded from YT, it shows the number of frames rendered by the browser.

You probably replayed all, or at least some parts of the video.

You can try it by searching a high quality video with a high fps count and playing it with that quality and then with the lower quality available, you are probably gonna see that in the high quality setting your browser is dropping frames.